# Problems converting GTiff to PDS with gdal

Tags: gdal, convert, file-formats, gdal-translate, nasa

I'm trying to convert a GTiff raster to a PDS raster (NASA Planetary Data System) using gdal_translate with this command:

`gdal_translate -of PDS -ot Float32 input.tif output.IMG`

But I get this error message: `0ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.`

Did I use the wrong input or is GDAL Drivers missing? I have GDAL 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `gdalinfo --formats|sort` in the OSGEO4W shell or a Linux terminal, you will get:

```
...
PDS -raster- (rov): NASA Planetary Data System
...
```

So there is no writing support for that format. http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pds.html does not offer more possibilities.

Comment: OK, I see, I thought the whole list from --formats was supported but now I learned that (rov) stands for read-only. Thank you! More info can be found here: http://gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html under --formats, for other people wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only software that has write support to PDS files is the ISIS: https://isis.astrogeology.usgs.gov/